# Why does ServiceStack reflect a forged ss-id cookie value back to the client?

Tags: servicestack

If I authenticate using ServiceStack's Auth Service under following route:
 **"/auth/credentials"**

and I forge / add the cookie **ss-id="BLABLA"** in the **request** ServiceStack sets the value **ss-id="BLABLA"** in the **response**. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if i can answer "why?" in terms of intent. But here is why in terms of code:

The [request.GetSessionId() extension](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/5111e706c64c2e062c87908901c3438d86c3d03e/src/ServiceStack/SessionFactory.cs#L63) will pull from the cookie (forged or not).

The [GetOrCreateSession()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/0c3bfd1fce6c69ced80a7bfcf2f77413aed754d8/src/ServiceStack/SessionFeature.cs#L69) in SessionFeature and SessionFactory will check the cache for an existing session, and use that. Otherwise, a new session will be created.

So it may be the case a new session is created with the ss-id "BLABLA".